# Accidentally executed yo angular-fullstack in wrong path

Tags: yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular, angular-fullstack

By mistake I executed command "yo angular-fullstack" in wrong folder. I want to know how to revert/delete the creation of app in this folder.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply just delete and go back to the path you want and re-run "yo angular-fullstack".